# Changing style of different zones in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have a javascript variable which it stores a geojson with different geographic zones (Polygons).

```
var geojsonObject = {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Zone A"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -5.925021171569824,
          43.58884625537951
        ],
        [
          -5.931243896484375,
          43.5882245752604
        ],
        [
          -5.929806232452392,
          43.58056184052945
        ],
        [
          -5.923476219177245,
          43.58129240699727
        ],
        [
          -5.924398899078369,
          43.588473248078564
        ],
        [
          -5.925021171569824,
          43.58884625537951
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Zone B"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -5.929784774780273,
          43.58042194381154
        ],
        [
          -5.928475856781006,
          43.57481026300195
        ],
        [
          -5.922789573669434,
          43.57522999129592
        ],
        [
          -5.923047065734863,
          43.57622489112154
        ],
        [
          -5.9233903884887695,
          43.57631816213746
        ],
        [
          -5.923454761505127,
          43.57765503082314
        ],
        [
          -5.922918319702148,
          43.57768612043941
        ],
        [
          -5.923347473144531,
          43.581121424150446
        ],
        [
          -5.929784774780273,
          43.58042194381154
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
]
};
```

I would like to apply different colours. For example: Zone A = red and Zone B = blue.

How can I show only one polygon on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snip to help you out. 
You do parse your geojson object as ol3 features. 
I have two style functions `styleFunction` for your first question(red, blue) and `hideStyleFunction` to show only one polygon out of two. 
To switch between these functions and see the result just assign it on your `style` attribute of your layer
eg.

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'added Layer',
      **style: styleFunction,//or change it style: hideStyleFunction,**
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
         features: OLfeatures 
      })
});
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/jmgyshrp/) and the full code

```
var geojsonObject = {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Zone A"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -5.925021171569824,
          43.58884625537951
        ],
        [
          -5.931243896484375,
          43.5882245752604
        ],
        [
          -5.929806232452392,
          43.58056184052945
        ],
        [
          -5.923476219177245,
          43.58129240699727
        ],
        [
          -5.924398899078369,
          43.588473248078564
        ],
        [
          -5.925021171569824,
          43.58884625537951
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Zone B"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -5.929784774780273,
          43.58042194381154
        ],
        [
          -5.928475856781006,
          43.57481026300195
        ],
        [
          -5.922789573669434,
          43.57522999129592
        ],
        [
          -5.923047065734863,
          43.57622489112154
        ],
        [
          -5.9233903884887695,
          43.57631816213746
        ],
        [
          -5.923454761505127,
          43.57765503082314
        ],
        [
          -5.922918319702148,
          43.57768612043941
        ],
        [
          -5.923347473144531,
          43.581121424150446
        ],
        [
          -5.929784774780273,
          43.58042194381154
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
]
};
var OLfeatures = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
         geojsonObject, 
         { 
         featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857', 
         dataProjection:'EPSG:4326' 
         })

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'added Layer',
      style: styleFunction,
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
         features: OLfeatures 
      })
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster,vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

function styleFunction(feature, resolution){
var styleToReturn;
  if (feature.get("name")==="Zone A"){
  styleToReturn = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'red',
          lineDash: [4],
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)'
        })
      })
  } else if  (feature.get("name")==="Zone B"){
  styleToReturn = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          lineDash: [4],
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)'
        })
      })
  }
  return styleToReturn;
}

function hideStyleFunction(feature, resolution){
var styleToReturn;
  if (feature.get("name")==="Zone A"){
  styleToReturn = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color:'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)'

        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)'
        })
      })
  } else if  (feature.get("name")==="Zone B"){
  styleToReturn = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          lineDash: [4],
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)'
        })
      })
  }
  return styleToReturn;
}

map.getView().fit(
vector.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry(), 
map.getSize());
```